# A point in multiple magnetic fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Given two parallel wires carrying a current (e.g. 2 and 3 Amperes) and the distance between them, 5 cm, how do I determine the magnitude of the magnetic field at a point M mid-distance between the wires (2.5 cm from each)?

The wires are located in a vacuum with ${\mu}=4\pi10^{-7}$.
If I use the formula 
$$B=\frac{\mu*I}{2*\pi*r}$$
and calculate the magnetic field for both currents/wires, how do I find the resulting magnetic field?

How do I do that, assuming the wires are perpendicular and in the same plane? How does this generalise to more than two wires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maxwell equations are linear equations, which implies that a linear combination of solutions is a solution itself.

That is, if you know the magnetic field $\vec B_1$ arising from a current $\vec j_1$, and the magnetic field $\vec B_2$ due to a current $\vec j_2$, you know that the magnetic field in the presence of both currents, i.e. the current $\vec j = \vec j_1 + \vec j_2$, is just the sum of the magnetic fields, namely $\vec B = \vec B_1 + \vec B_2$.

This is a little harder to implement using your formula, as it only gives you the magnitude of the magnetic field and not its direction, but I am positive that you will be able to figure that out, using, for example, the [Right Hand Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_hand_rule#Direction_associated_with_a_rotation) on both wires to determine the direction of the magnetic field and then add the relevant components together.

Comment: Actually, I was given a drawing too..I forgot to mention the direction of magnetic field :D. Thanks!